# Python function with if statements for python requests query

Tags: python, if-statement, python-requests

I'm trying to add if/else statement into my function to prevent updating email (for corresponding emailId in the emailId list) with priority and notes IF notes already exist.

my code:

```
emailId = [732853380, 7331635674]
customerId = ['cust-12345-mer', 'cust-6789-mer']

def update_email(emailId, token, user, priority=4, notes="my note goes here"):
    headers = {     'accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'token': token,
                    'user': user}
    endpoint = 'request/'
    if notes != "":
        body = {'emailId': emailId, 'unassignEmail': True}
    else:
        body = {'emailId': emailId, 'unassignEmail': True, 'priority': priority,'notes': notes}
    requests.put(url = host + endpoint, headers = headers, json=body)
    return True

    for x, y in zip(emailId, customerId):
        update_email(x, token, user, priority=4, notes="my note goes here" + y )
```

When I run the above I receive response 'True' for each item on the list. However, the email for emailId which has no notes is not being updated with notes and priority. Could someone please help me get this right? not sure what I'm doing wrong. thanks!

Comment: Your function _always_ returns `True` because of `return True` at the end. Also, you're _always_ supplying the `notes` argument (`update_email(..., notes="https://...")`), so is the function, `notes != ""` will always be true, and no priority or notes will be supplied in the body.

Comment: Your function returns True regardless of the status of the request so yeah every time you call it you will get True